# Return AWSError on sinon stub typescript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, sinon

I have this function:

```js
export async function checkIfUserExist(user: User): Promise<boolean> {
  let result: PromiseResult<QueryOutput, AWSError>;

  const params = {
    TableName: "Users",
    IndexName: "Email-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "Email = :user_email",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":user_email": user.Email
    }
  }

  result = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();

  if (result.$response.error != null) {
    console.log(`Error query: ${result.$response.error}`)
    return true;
  } else if (result.Count > 0) {
    console.log(`User already exist`)
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to test it using mocha/chai and Sinon to mocks. I'm trying to return a AWSError to test the first `if` statement. The code of my test is this:

```js
it('With error @ query', async () => {
    const errorStub = Sinon.stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'query')
    const input: User = {
      Email: "pleaseneverregisteruserwiththisemail@gmail.com"
    };
    const expectedOutput: boolean = false;
    const output = await checkIfUserExist(input);

    expect(output).to.equal(expectedOutput);
    expect(errorStub.calledOnce).true;
    Sinon.restore();
  })
```

How can I return a AWSError in the errorStub ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you get the 'dynamodb` variable? What is the type of the variable? Where is it instantiated?

Comment: @stijndepestel the variable is globally instantiated at the beginning of the file where the `checkIfUserExist` function is

Comment: I thought the stub wasn't working correctly, but on second read I see that it simply wasn't there. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a stub, so as you can see in [the documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubthrows), it is as easy as calling the correct function on the stub:

```js
const errorStub = Sinon.stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'query');
errorStub.throws(new AWSError());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stub the return value of `dynamodb.query()` method which has a `.promise()` method. After that, you also need to stub the resolved value of `.promise()` method to `AWSError`.

`index.ts`:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export async function checkIfUserExist(user): Promise<boolean> {
  let result;

  const params = {
    TableName: 'Users',
    IndexName: 'Email-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'Email = :user_email',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':user_email': user.Email,
    },
  };

  result = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();

  if (result.$response.error != null) {
    console.log(`Error query: ${result.$response.error}`);
    return true;
  } else if (result.Count > 0) {
    console.log(`User already exist`);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import AWS, { AWSError } from 'aws-sdk';
import { DocumentClient } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { checkIfUserExist } from '.';

describe('68761832', () => {
  it('With error @ query', async () => {
    const mReq = { promise: sinon.stub().resolves({ $response: { error: new Error('network') } }) };
    const queryStub = sinon
      .stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'query')
      .returns((mReq as unknown) as AWS.Request<DocumentClient.QueryOutput, AWSError>);
    const input = {
      Email: 'pleaseneverregisteruserwiththisemail@gmail.com',
    };
    const output = await checkIfUserExist(input);
    expect(output).to.equal(true);
    expect(queryStub.calledOnce).true;
    expect(mReq.promise.calledOnce).true;
    sinon.restore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  68761832
Error query: Error: network
    ✓ With error @ query


  1 passing (6ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   66.67 |       25 |     100 |   66.67 |                   
 index.ts |   66.67 |       25 |     100 |   66.67 | 22-26             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```